# Practices to convert computer algorithms to matheamtical notations

Tags: algorithms, education

First, an example:
Given an image (2D array) to write down a mathematical notation for the function of pixelation, for example.

[image: pixelation]
*Fig. 0: The pixelated version (right) of the given 2D array (left)*

**What would be a mathematical notation for the above simple function?**

The second part:
**How about many everyday computing algorithms that can apply on any arbitrary dimensional data if one wants to write them down in mathematical notation? You as a computer scientist how would you start, proceed and finalise?** Consider the case that your work will be checked by a pure mathematician!

---

*to whom may can please add a new tag math-notation*

Comment: Thanks for posting on SciComp! As posed, it's not clear to me what you're asking. I'm going to attempt an answer, and I'm also going to close the question for now. The second part also seems too broad. I'm not even sure if this site is the right place for your question.

Comment: I think that the words *You as a computer scientist * suggest that OP is confusing *computer science* and *computational science*.  This seems like a question for the former audience rather than the latter.

Comment: I would guess that the Computer Science Stack Exchange site would be a better fit than CS Theory Stack Exchange; the latter is explicitly geared towards researchers in theoretical computer science, and this question is not a research-level question in theoretical computer science.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the first part of your question: there are probably many functions that achieve the same goal, so "what would be a mathematical notation for the above simple function" will have many answers. For instance, the image could be coarsened by decreasing the resolution by one-half in each dimension so that each pixel in the coarse image corresponds to four pixels in the original image, and the pixel color could be determined by averaging, in which case you could use algebraic formulas with indexing. The few signal processing questions we've gotten on here have used special notation for filters; I am not familiar with signal processing, so I can't really describe it well, or what it means.

The second part of your question on the correspondence between algorithms and mathematical notation is broad. To give a brief overview, the Church-Turing thesis states that any function that is "algorithmically calculable" if and only if it can be computed by Turing machine. So a facile answer would be, "Any algorithm can be expressed in mathematical notation as a Turing machine." Few people describe algorithms in this manner. You'll see it in a theory of computation class, but you wouldn't see it in an undergraduate introduction to algorithms class. What seems to be more common for algorithmic description is pseudocode. There's no standard pseudocode used everywhere, but one common variant can be found in the algorithms textbook by Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest, and Stein. You can find pseudocode also in several applied mathematics papers in SIAM journals; more mathematical algorithms tend to involve equations with standard notation that augment some sort of pseudocode like that in the Cormen, et al. book. Others simply describe their algorithm in long-form sentences, again using mathematical notation as needed. If it's short enough, some include MATLAB code (or similar sorts of code) in their papers. If the program used to implement an algorithm is long, typically some sort of description is given; the program may or may not be accessible to readers.

As for your comment about pure mathematicians, that really depends on audience as well. In more formal settings (computer science classes, some research settings like certain mathematics journals), a proof may be required to show that a proposed algorithm achieves its stated objectives. In less formal settings, the algorithm may simply be stated without proof; exposition without proof is more common in journals with a less mathematically rigorous readership, such as some applications-oriented engineering journals.

So both of your questions have many answers, and the latter is certainly open to interpretation and preference.